# Lookup field for files on current record

Tags: lookup-field

I'm trying to create a lookup field for files on the same record, such that a user can select a specific file from the list of files that they've uploaded.

I've seen some resources pointing to creating a lookup to the ContentDocument object, but that's not something you can even choose in object manager when within the current object you're trying to add the lookup field onto.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can't create standard lookup fields to contentdocument, contentdocumentlink or contentversion you can create a text field named fileId and a formula field that shows a url if fileId is populated so user can click on it.

you can then then create a screenflow where you can populate fileId by creating a record choice set of all contentDocumentLinks related to your record with a picklist component.

you can choose to have your screenflow being triggered from a button on your page or have it embedded on the lightning page itself.

Comment: Thanks but wound't contentDocumentLinks just show a dropdown of the link id in salesforce, rather than the name of the file?

Comment: @user1702965 you can use the quickchoice component at unofficial SF to create dropdowns from 2 collections of strings to bind id's to fields of other objects https://unofficialsf.com/quick-choice-improved-picklists-and-radio-buttons-for-flow/